# Autocomplete result is very slow on input field search

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a input field. When the user type some value then it must autocomplete based on the user search. I am using following code. I am getting the data but it gets very slow if result is more than 50 and sometimes system crash out.

How can I improve my code so that it works fine.

```
$( "#cc" ).autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('registration/getData'); ?>",
            data: { term: $("#cc").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.response == "true"){
                    response(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

Comment: increase the delay and minLength

Comment: because you got no delay/debouncing and your doing a query after first char.. your hammering your server.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how to add delay?

Comment: Try to increase the `delay` and `minLength`. If you give 0 or 1 it will affect your server.

Comment: @user1687891 _"how to add delay?"_: you now have `delay: 0`. A good guess to increase that would be to make it greater than 0, right?

Comment: RTM: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay

Answer (score 0):

You should use a debounce (look it up, Very usefull) and your API should return a max of 5 records. Add to the query a LIMIT. If you use the api call for another function where you do want alot of users at ones. Make the LIMIT dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using throttle / debounce or at least use a delay.
This will allow you to reduce load to your server and provide a better more responsive experience to your users.

In short:

Throttle: the original function be called at most once per specified period.

Debounce: the original function be called after the caller stops calling the decorated function after a specified period.

Comment: I tried debounce as follow:     $('#cc').keyup($.debounce(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('registration/getData'); ?>",
            data: { term: $("#cc").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.response == "true"){
                    response(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 300)); but it is giving problem

Comment: what kind of problem, could you please be specific?